# PERL: reading Log file and cmd line input together

Tags: perl, stdin

I have written a script which is reading some data from log file and transform the data to simpler form and writing it back to another file. the reading is done line by line with a delay of 5 seconds i.e. sleep(5).

Meanwhile, on the command line if a user enters 'suspend' (through STDIN) then the program went on to sleep unless 'resume' is not entered and then read the next line.

Since, with every iteration in the loop I am checking STDIN whether 'suspend' is entered or not by the user.

if not then read the next line from the file. but when my programs runs I have to at least hit a ENTER key, otherwise it does not picks the next line from the input log file albeit i put an if statement to check if STDIN is undefined or not.

I am not a perl expert and this the first time I am writing a code in PERL. infact i have never done this file parsing thing before :'-(

my code implementation is like this;

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
my $line_no = 0;my $cancel = 0; my $line = "";
my $curpos = 0; my $whence = 0;

my $log_file = "/var/log/tmp_nagios.log";
#open(LOGFILE, "+< $log_file")or die "Failed to open $log_file, $!";

my $inp_file = "/var/log/sec_input";
my $logbuffer="";

#open(LOGFILE, "+< $log_file")or die "Failed to open $log_file, $!";
my $in;

while(1){
    print "in While (1) Pos: $curpos and Whence:$whence\n";

    open(LOGFILE, "+< $log_file")or die "Failed to open $log_file, $!";
    seek(LOGFILE, $curpos, $whence);
    next if(eof(LOGFILE));

    print "Beginning\n";
    while(<LOGFILE>){
            #chomp($in = <STDIN>);
            #if(defined($in) && $in =~ /^suspend$/i){
            ### Problem here ###
            if(defined(<STDIN>) && <STDIN> =~ /^suspend\n$/i){ ## checking if 'suspend' is entered
                    print "Suspend Mode";
                    do{
                            sleep(5);
                    }while(!(<STDIN> =~ /^resume\n$/i));
                    print "Resume now\n";
                    close(LOGFILE);
                    last;
            }
            else{
                    $line = $_;
                    if($line =~ m/^\[(\d+)\]\sCURRENT\sSERVICE\sSTATE:\s(\w+);(\w+|\_|\d+)+;(CRITICAL|OK);.+$/){
                            $logbuffer = "$1,$2-$3,$4\n";
                            print $logbuffer;
                            open(INPFILE, ">> $inp_file")or die "Failed! to open $inp_file, $!";
                            #print INPFILE $logbuffer;
                            close(INPUTFILE);
                            sleep(5);
                            $curpos = tell(LOGFILE);
                            $whence = 1;
                    }
            }
    }
    print "\nRe openning the file from Pos=$curpos and Whence=$whence\n";
   }
   close(LOGFILE);
```

here is the sample log file (/var/log/tmp_nagios.log) data;

[1284336000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: host1;event1;CRITICAL; s

[1284336000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: host2;event1;CRITICAL; f

[1284336000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: host3;event3;CRITICAL; g

[1284336000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: host4;event4;CRITICAL; j

[1284336000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: host5;event1;CRITICAL; s

[1284336000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: host6;event1;CRITICAL; f

[1284336000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: host7;event7;CRITICAL; s

---

Sorry guys! Typo mistake

In the beginning I said, 'my script is reading data from log file with a delay of 5 seconds i.e. sleep(5)'

but actually i forget to mention it in my code, therefore, uncomment this line: #sleep(3); and make 'sleep(5);'

thanks

Comment: it would be better if your post had the question in it. I do see the comment in the code about the suspend check thing. The code is kinda cluttered with commented-out sections, though. For now, I'd suggest that you simplify the code into just the loop that parses the log file, get that working, and _then_ add in the signal check for the pause/resume.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly: check out the `Term::ReadKey` CPAN Module.

You can use it to do non-blocking buffer reads. (If there is nothing in the buffer, your script does not pause for user input)

https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey

You may also like to approach this problem slightly differently - using signals:
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html. You can have your program run normally, but capture interrupts (e.g. `CTRL-C`)

Alternatively, you could just use `CTRL-Z` and `fg` to make your script sleep and wake.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [POE::Wheel::FollowTail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE%3a%3aWheel%3a%3aFollowTail) for the log and [POE::Wheel::ReadLine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE%3a%3aWheel%3a%3aReadLine) or [Term::Visual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-Visual/) for user input.  Though this might be a little overkill